# Visual Code отключить подсветку знаков табуляции

Tags: visual-studio-code

При редактирование *JavaScript* такая штука непонятная.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где выключить?

[image: непонятная штука]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. За это отвечает опция "Live Matching" в настройках.
[image: done]